# Row Count in Selenium restricted to first 70 rows

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, html-table, grid, rowcount

I have a table on the webpage which gets populated with rows based on search-filters.
The number of rows vary from 1 to 200 base don above.

However, when the number of rows are more than 70, the script selects only first 70 rows. therefore, it loops through only the first 70 rows.

Why is it happening and how can I make the script select all the rows?
I have tried zooming the browser from 100% to 75% and 67%, still the same.

code:

```
grid_rows = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,
                                         "/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/ptcs-tab-set/ptcs-mb-container/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr")

time.sleep(5)
print(len(grid_rows))
```

Comment: I can't see any reason why that code would limit the number of rows returned. Is it possible that the data is split into multiple tables? Or maybe the website uses dynamic scrolling, so it doesn't add the higher rows to the table until you scroll to them.

Comment: Scrolling could be the reason. In that case I have to use a code to keep scrolling?

Comment: Yes. You should be able to see this in the browser's DevTools.